# Java 2D Perlin Noise for Random Terrain Generation

Tags: java

My name is Chris and I'm working on my first Java game.
Thus far, I have created a tile based 2D game, however my level is done in such a way so that if I create an image and its all green, then that green would stand for a grass tile. If I put a pixel of blue, the game would assign that as a water tile.

However, that limits the game to how I design the level, I'd much rather have an infinite terrain of tiles.

Being a beginner, I looked up different ways to do so. A particularly poignant method was something called a Perlin Noise.

I looked into it but it seemed very complex.

Would somebody mind defining it in simpler terms?

Also, if you have any tutorials that 'dumb' it down a bit and give a brief overview, that'd be fantastic!

Sorry I haven't been too specific, I'm actually avoiding from doing so.

Comment: Not completely sure what you want to achieve, but from what I get it seems Perlin noise is not the right tool for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem fit for me without any doubt,
Worst I could do is give it a try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perlin noise was brilliantly covered by [Daniel Shiffman](https://twitter.com/shiffman) on **[The Nature Of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/introduction/)**. It's an online book that has awesome Javascript/ProcessingJS sample code to demonstrate some of the important concepts:

> A good random number generator produces numbers that have no relationship and show no discernible pattern. As we are beginning to see, a little bit of randomness can be a good thing when programming organic, lifelike behaviors. However, randomness as the single guiding principle is not necessarily natural. An algorithm known as **“Perlin noise”**, named for its inventor **Ken Perlin**, takes this concept into account. Perlin developed the noise function while working on the original **Tron movie** in the early 1980s; it was designed to create procedural textures for computer-generated effects. In 1997 Perlin won an Academy Award in technical achievement for this work. Perlin noise can be used to generate various effects with natural qualities, such as clouds, landscapes, and patterned textures like marble.
>
> **Perlin noise has a more organic appearance** because it produces a naturally ordered (“smooth”) sequence of pseudo-random numbers. The graph on the left below shows Perlin noise over time, with the x-axis representing time; note the smoothness of the curve. The graph on the right shows pure random numbers over time.

[image]
*(The code for generating these graphs is available in the accompanying book downloads.)*

**Khan Academy** dedicated the entire *advanced Javascript* lessons to dissect some of the stuff  shown by Shiffman on his book. They have great [lessons on randomness](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/cs/programming-natural-simulations/programming-randomness/a/random-walks), and of course, one just for the [Perlin noise](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/cs/programming-natural-simulations/programming-noise/a/perlin-noise).

Comment: Thank you very much. Well summed up and love the back story behind it. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

I'd suggest **skipping Perlin Noise** and taking a look at something called **[OpenSimplex Noise](https://gist.github.com/KdotJPG/b1270127455a94ac5d19)**.

It's useful for basically all of the same things as Perlin Noise, but it has significantly fewer visible directional artifacts. Basically, the noise takes an input coordinate (in 2D, 3D, or 4D) and returns a value between -1 and 1. The output values vary continuously with the input coordinate changes.

Here are three 256x256 images generated using noise (x / 24.0, y / 24.0):

[image]

- The first one is the raw noise
- The second one is green where the values are greater than zero, and blue otherwise
- The third one is blue where the values are greater than -0.2 and less than 0.2, and green otherwise.

Note that there's also Simplex Noise (different algorithm from OpenSimplex) that has reduced directional artifacts compared to Perlin Noise, but the 3D and higher implementations of Simplex Noise (if you happen to want to use 3D noise to vary anything in 2D over time) are saddled with a patent.

OpenSimplex Noise is actually an algorithm I've developed for a game of my own, so shameless plug I know, but I think it's the best for you out of what's available.

Answer (score 1):

You are not obliged to get the full understanding of the perlin or simplex implementation immediately. You can slowly learn while playing with parameters of the various methods you will find. Just use it by feeding x,y, possibly z or more dimension arguments with the coordinates of a grid for example. To keep it simple, you basically mix/superimpose several layers(octaves) of interpolated random images at different scales .

You may also want to evaluate and store your noise offline because of the processing charge it may imply if used at run-time (although depending on the resolution / octaves and your processing budget or testing purposes, you can achieve quite decent real time frame rates too).